# Theme My Login Shortcode Doesn’t Return Anything

Tags: plugins, themes, login

I have created a new page with the slug /login. In this page I have added a short code:

```
[theme-my-login action=“login” show_links="0"]
```

And in the TML plugin settings page, I have set the right slug for the login form location (login).

After all of this, when I go to the login page of my website, the login form doesn’t show up.

Although I do not have a page for reset password set up, when visiting the resetpass page, the reset password form shows up.

What’s going on and how do I fix this?

Comment: Two questions (1) are you viewing this while already logged in? (2) What is providing the shortcode - is it a plugin or a custom theme?

Comment: (1) I’ve tried it logged in, logged out and on a completely different device signed out, (2) I’m using the Theme My Login Plugin

Comment: It could be the quotes if the code you have pasted is the exact code you're using. Notice around the word `login` the quotes are curly rather than straight. Try pasting the same straight quotes you have around the number `0`.

Comment: Maybe they're having a character encoding issue, but all I see in that doc is straight quotes. Curly quotes are different ASCII characters and are a common source of issues. You can always contact the plugin support team directly and more likely find a faster answer.

Comment: @WebElaine turns out you’re indeed correct. I copied the quotation marks used in the show_links attribute and used it with the action attribute and it works fine. Would you like to post that so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the quotes if the code you have pasted is the exact code you're using. Notice around the word `login` the quotes are curly rather than straight. Try pasting the same straight quotes you have around the number `0`.